# Create resource bundle key with variable (Primefaces)

Tags: primefaces

How can I retrieve value of resource bundle with dynamic bean property ?

I want to get value of `LOCALE_EN` or `LOCALE_FR` key. `EN` or `FR` are propery value bean.

I tested :

```
#{rb["LOCALE_" + selected.localeChoice]}
#{rb[LOCALE_ + selected.localeChoice]}
#{rb.LOCALE_[selected.localeChoice]}
...
```

with no result

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's just

```
#{rb["LOCALE_".concat(selected.localeChoice)]}
```